# Is it fair to vote down questions?

Tags: discussion

As a newcomer, I do not know the point of voting down questions, also I do not know if my this question will be voted down, seemingly very likely.

I just want to know the reason, why you should vote down questions? Yes, some questions are naive, but I think everyone joins Stack Overflow hoping to find an answer, no matter how novice they are, they have the rights to post questions.

My suggestion is that, you could put some constrains, say, setting up multiple sects according to reputation points, like 0-200, 200-500, 500-1000, 1000-2000, 2000-5000, 5000-10000, >10000, etc. You can only post questions and answers in your sect not above, but everyone has the right to browse all sects. I think this is fair, and give newcomers more opportunities to post their questions and to grow their reputation points. I would like know how many people share my opinion.

Comment: See e.g. [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) and the downvote button tooltip: *"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*.

Comment: You may check what's written [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) about the expected behavior.

Comment: You know reputation has nothing to do with a person's skill? To some extend a person answered 100 dumb question could have higher rep than other guy that answer just handful of extreme questions.

Comment: _'setting up multiple sects according to reputation'_ No! This destroys democracy! There shouldn't be users _'more equal'_ than others here.

Comment: Another poor soul who does not understand what the site is about and complains before reading at least the help center. I have no idea what we could do about these people.

Comment: Just FYI. When I see a poorly formated post that does not contain a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I'm much more likely to DV if it is an experienced user.

Answer (score 19):

> Is it fair to downvote questions.

Yes, it's entirely fair - and it exists for a reason. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site where the **best** questions and answers should rise to the top of the pile. Up and downvoting is the method by which this is achieved.

If you look at the tooltip on the downvote button, you'll find the following:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

Downvoting questions allows those who wish to provide answers with a clear indicator as to whether the community thinks the question is both clear and beneficial to other programmers.

It is important to understand that down and close-voting serve different purposes, though you'll often find that poorly constructed questions regularly also fall faul of the post guidelines.

More:

- [Help center on downvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)
- [Stack Exchange: Why do you cast downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/why-do-you-cast-downvotes-on-answers)

Comment: As I suggested, why not setting up a novice sect to allow every question posted, and if you think that question too naive, you can just ignore it. Maybe some new guys would like to answer the questions, and have some discussion. You high reputation guys can have your own reputation system.

Comment: @dguan: That's just creating a ghetto, effectively. Surely it's better to set and maintain a high quality bar. There's no reason why a newcomer can't post decent questions, and many do. It's just a matter of actually caring and reading a bit about what's expected.

Comment: @dguan Because Stackoverflow is not a forum, it is a question and answer site. It is not part of the site's remit to answer every and any question that someone might have - only those which fall within a certain set of criteria and quality standards.

Comment: Because the next @JonSkeet is going to come to this site with 0 rep, and he'll be unable to entertain the rest of the high reppers with his knowledge of Shanghai timezones and ponies. You shouldn't be penalised from contributing questions or answers based on reputation.

Comment: Well, I think I have a better understanding of the point, yet it costed me, let me see, 16 repus. I would like to draw my question back, should I delete it, or you think it's better to keep it as is?

Comment: @dugan Downvotes on meta can signify (amongst other things) disagreement with your proposal or complaint. They don't affect your rep on the main site, don't worry about them

Comment: @dguan you can't remove it now since it has up-voted answers against it. It also should provide benefit to users in the future who might wish to post a similar proposal (but it is unlikely to be discoverable given your choice of summary).

Answer (score 7):

Downvoting almost always means that you, either:

- Haven't researched **on** Stack Overflow enough, and the question has already been discussed
- Your post lacks a real question
- You've failed to describe what your actual problem is.

Usually I downvote for these reasons.

You can check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) and find the rules over there.

Answer (score 6):

It is completely fair to downvote questions especially when considering the severe amount of low-quality questions that flow in every day.  The downvote tooltip explains why to downvote:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

A question that does not show effort or is unclear is not a quality question, thus, deserves downvotes.

As for the different sectors, I don't really see what that would accomplish, but that is just my personal view.  A user with 1 reputation *definitely may* be able to provide a quality answer to a user with 20k reputation.

Answer (score -17):

As I suggested, why not setting up a novice sect to allow every question posted, and if you think that question too naive, you can just ignore it. Maybe some new guys would like to answer the questions, and have some discussion. You high reputation guys can have your own reputation system.

Comment: Sorry, but why does the new user come in and get to tell the existing users how they should be acting, how the site should be run, and so on? Take a step back and realise that this site has been positively thriving for a number of years, _because_ of the way things are done. Not in spite of them.

Comment: How about if novices just asked decent quality questions? It isn't a *difficulty* problem, it's a *basic comprehension* problem.

Comment: Over 95% of the downvotes could have been avoided if newcomers read  [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)